# Cannot find mistake in exponentiation when trying to simplify a general sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am dealing with a general sequence, $a_n$, for which $S_n$ is the sequence of its partial sums.
I know that $a_n = S_{n} - S_{n-1}$, **and therefore $a_n = S_{n+1} - S_{n}$ 
also.**

I want to find $a_n$ given:
$$ S_n = k - \frac{1}{3^{n+1}} $$

Here is the correct, confirmed calculation:
$$ a_n = S_{n} - S_{n-1} = k - \frac{1}{3^{n+1}} - k +\frac{1}{3^n}$$
$$ a_n = \frac{1}{3^n} - \frac{1}{3^{n+1}}$$
$$ a_n = \frac{1-3^{-1}}{3^n} $$
$$ a_n = \frac{2/3}{3^n} $$
$$ \boxed{a_n = \frac{2}{3^{n+1}}}$$

Fine and dandy, but when I try to solve it from a different angle, I get a wrong answer and can't understand where have I went wrong:

$$ a_n = S_{n+1} - S_{n} = k - \frac{1}{3^{n+2}} - k +\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}$$
$$ a_n = \frac{1}{3^{n+1}} - \frac{1}{3^{n+2}}$$
$$ a_n = \frac{3^{n+2} - 3^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}\cdot 3^{n+2}} $$
$$ a_n = \frac{3^n(3^2 - 3^1)}{3^{2n+3}} $$
$$ a_n = \frac{3^n(3^2 - 3^1)}{3^{2n}(3^3)} $$
$$ a_n = \frac{3^{n - 2n}(3^2 - 3^1)}{3^3} = \frac{3^{-n}(9 - 3)}{27} = \frac{6}{27\cdot 3^n} = \frac{2}{9\cdot 3^n} \boxed{\neq \frac{2}{3^{n+2}}}$$

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not true that $a_n=S_{n+1}-S_n$. What is true is $a_{n+1}=S_{n+1}-S_n$

Comment: Unsure why this had a downvote. It's a clear question with a clear answer, and a good example of how easy it can be to look in the wrong place for a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is not correct in general! if $a_n = S_n - S_{n-1}$ then $a_{n+1} = S_{n+1} - S_n$. A contradiction for this is your example.

Your assumption will be true if the difference of each $S_{i} - S_{i-1}$ be a constant for all $i$. Hence, $S_{i+1} = S_i + c$ for all $i$. Therefore, $a_{n+1} = S_{n+1}-S_n = a_{n} =S_{n} - S_{n-1}= c$.

Comment: Thank you. I am unsure what drove me to assume that in general.

Comment: @daedsidog my pleasure. take it easy. ; )